# Is sky a countable noun or an uncountable noun?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Is "sky" a countable noun or an uncountable noun?

We can count the sky as it is only one, but it's that people refer to as it being uncountable.

Comment: Also in science fiction where each planet has its own.

Answer (score 1):

If we use the term our usual way, yes, there is one sky.

Cambridge Dictionary, however, also has this definition:

skies [ plural ]

the sky in a particular state or place:
For weeks we had cloudless blue skies.
We're off to the sunny skies of Florida.

Ngram shows also significant use of 'skies'.

We may deduce that it is countable.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&content=Skies&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSkies%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Perhaps it's an uncountable plural.